# Can I use ReportPortal with nightwatchjs?

Tags: reportportal

Can I use ReportPortal with nightwatchjs + mocha?
If someone has experience, then tell in details please!
P.s.: Now for reporting I use mochawesome-report-generator.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such integration right now. But REST API is documented so you can write it on your own. Feel free to contact development team in [slack](https://reportportal-slack-auto.herokuapp.com/) if you need any assistance

Answer (score 1):

request submitted into backlog.
watch it for updates
https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/140